# subclassing uiView > unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, subclass

I am trying to subclass UIView as BottomNavBar (code below).
I get the following error

```
'-[UIView setCenterImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14dc5050'
```

setting a couple of breakpoints the error comes from this line

```
self.centerImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_OK.png"];  //I used it just for testing it should be as follows: 
self.centerImage=centerIcon;
```

BottomNavBar.m

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame centerIcon:(UIImage*)centerIcon withFrame:(CGRect)centerFrame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        self=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
        [self setBackgroundColor:UA_NAV_BAR_COLOR];

        //--------------------------------------------------
        self.centerImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_OK.png"]; //for testing
        //self.centerImage=centerIcon; >>this is the one that should be used
        self.centerImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:centerFrame];
        self.centerImageView.image=self.centerImage;
        [self addSubview:self.centerImageView];            
    }
    return self;
}
```

cropPhoto.m (where I'm trying to show an object of that class...)

```
CGRect bottomBarFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-UA_BOTTOM_BAR_HEIGHT, self.view.frame.size.width, UA_BOTTOM_BAR_HEIGHT);
    NSLog(@"UA_icon_ok: %@", UA_ICON_OK);
    self.bottomNavBar = [[BottomNavBar alloc] initWithFrame:bottomBarFrame centerIcon:UA_ICON_OK withFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 90, 45)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.bottomNavBar];
```

can anybody help on what's going wrong here?

Comment: setCenterImage -> add this method in .h file of bottom nav bar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `self=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];`

Remove this line. Your view is already initialised, now you're replacing the value of self with a plain UIView.

I'm surprised you're not seeing a compiler warning here.

Comment: it wont be a warning. its warning in other custom methods but not in init kind of methods which return id

Comment: thanks! I was headbanging for ours and couldn't figure it out. but this totally makes sense!!